# How to make a query on two fields in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to make a query on two fields sender_id or recipient_id if the id is in one of the fields sender_id or recipient_id to make the selection according to him

query

```
@recipients = Company.joins(:invitations).where(invitations: {sender_id: @company.id OR recipient_id: @company.id,confirm: true})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @recipients = Company.joins(:invitations).where("invitations.confirm = ? and (invitations.sender_id = ? or invitations.recipient_id = ?)", true, @company.id, @company.id)
```